# woocommerce graphql registerUser, sometime work something dont

Tags: woocommerce, next.js, graphql

i am sending data to make woocommerce graphql reigster a user, but sometimes it work some time it dont, speicalily once i succesful register a user, then right ahead to register again it wont register again. after i wait a while or refresh the page, it can be register again, is woocommerce graphql have somekind of delay system to prevent register spam, so i know is not my code problem. here is my code

```
const [username, setUsername] = useState('')
const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
const [password, setPassword] = useState('')

const [registerUser, { data, error, isLoading }] = client.useMutation((mutation, args: FormData) => {
    const result = mutation.registerUser({
        input: args,
    })
    console.log('REsult', result)
    return result.user
})

const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    await registerUser({
        args: {
            username,
            email,
            password,
        },
    })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log('error:', error)
        })
        .then((response) => {
            console.log('response:', response)
        })
}

useEffect(() => {
    console.log(data)

    setUsername('')
    setEmail('')
    setPassword('')
}, [data])
```

here is my html:

```
return (
    <div className="ps-page--default">
            <form className="ps-form--auth" id="register__tab">
                        <div className="ps-tabs">
                            <div id="tab-2">
                                <div className="form-group form-group--space">
                                    <input
                                        className="form-control"
                                        name="username"
                                        id="register__tab--username"
                                        type="text"
                                        placeholder="What should we call you ?"
                                        value={username}
                                        onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
                                    />
                                </div>
                                <div className="form-group form-group--space">
                                    <input
                                        className="form-control"
                                        name="email"
                                        id="register__tab--email"
                                        type="email"
                                        placeholder="Enter your email"
                                        value={email}
                                        onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                                    />
                                </div>
                                <div className="form-group form-group--space">
                                    <input
                                        className="form-control"
                                        name="password"
                                        id="register__tab--password"
                                        type="text"
                                        placeholder="Create a password"
                                        value={password}
                                        onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                                    />
                                </div>
            <div className="ps-form__desc">
                <p>Your personal data will be used to support your experience throughout this website, to manage access to your account, and for other purposes described in our privacy policy.
                </p>
                </div>
                    <div className="form-group submit">
                        <button type="submit" className="ps-btn ps-btn--fullwidth ps-btn--black" disabled={isLoading} onClick={handleSubmit}>
                                        {isLoading ? 'Signing up...' : 'Sign up'}
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
)
```

do anyone know what do i miss ? or is just part of woocommerce graphql setting ?

the only error show on my console.log are this

```
[gqty] Warning! No data requested.
resolved2 @ resolvers.mjs?c4ac:167
```

others are all my successful return

Comment: "sometimes it work some time it dont"

Please provide the errors you get

Comment: thanks i update my post, please give a look at it.

Comment: Could you console.log your args before they are sent to registerUser ?